# how can we control traffic on kafka partition

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm creating a grayscale deployment strategy for my kafka workload. This is being done to control the release of new changes. I want to achieve a strategy wherein i can make live new changes on 1% of total messages on kafka topic for a consumer group.
For this i need to control traffic from producer on one partition.  If i have 3 partitions taking 33% traffic each and 1 partition which is  taking 1% , and if we can fix a consumer on this partition, we can achieve the grayscale deployment.

Please let me know if this is possible with kafka.  If yes, how?
Or is there any better way to control traffic on consumer specific deployments?

Comment: You can define your partitioner to send data in any percentage you want

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer. Can you please mention some reference link, how can we achieve this?

Comment: Refer Kafka documentation producer property: `partitioner.class`